# back doesn't work properly when navigating from notification in closed app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

When I navigate from a notification in closed app i'm able to navigate to the required screen. 
The app navigates to dashboard when i click on the hardware back button, but when i  go back from a custom back button in toolbar header it navigates to the dashboard(as required) but instantly comes back to the same page.

**Navigating from a notification:**

```
this.props.navigation.push("screen", {
    data: somedata,
})
```

**Navigating back to dashboard:**

```
this.props.navigation.push('Dashboard')
```

I also tried using ResetAction function but it had the same results.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to , your screen is not stack that time, for that You have firstly push that screen to stack and navigate it. 
And without any operation of notification click , its default open the app first screen.

You should use this code when you press on notification tray.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('XYZScreen'{itemID:id,fromWhere:"NOTIFICATION"})
```

this line navigate you to **XYZScreen** with this keys params. and there you can identify that you are coming from **NOTIFICATION** . so according this you can come back the any screen.

Please use this code , it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

because you don't have any screen in stack 
please use replace function like 
`this.props.navigation.replace('Dashboard')`

and for hardware back press use backHander and same code in that listener function